# Notepad++ how to delete second set of same character in a line

Tags: set, character, notepad++

I have a text files that contains multiple lines, each line has the following format

```
string1/string2/string3
```

all 3 strings are arbitrary. I want to remove `/string3` for all lines.

Anyone have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `CTRL + H`
2. Select `Regular expression`
3. Type `/(\w)+$` into `Find what`
4. Replace with nothing

Of course you may have to fiddle around with the regular expression according to your data, but that's the way to go.

Comment: Great. Thank you t3hn00b. i have tried some hours with `.*?` but could not get it done

Comment: @PamApple welcome to this nice community. You may accept the answer if it worked for you...